# Javascript function returns variables as undefined

Tags: javascript, function, variables, undefined

I am dynamically including a javascript file into a html page, which works fine. But when I run the function 'tryData' from the file the variables return as undefined. I've been looking for hours can't find a similar problem anywhere, does anyone know what the problem is?

function in external file:

```
function tryData(id, size){
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '<iframe src="http://domain.com/feeds/'+id+'/'+size+'/" id="frame"></iframe>';
    if(window.data){
        clearInterval(timer);
        data();
    }
}
```

the line I am using to call it:

```
tryData(131, 'large');
```

I know that the function is running because the frame is inserted as expected, but there's no content as the URL for the frame reads 'domain.com/feeds/undefined/undefined/', instead of 'domain.com/feeds/131/large/'.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

---

Here is an example of a html page with the function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>


    <!-- Widget -->
    <div id="content"></div>    
    <script>
    (function(d, s) {
    var js = d.createElement(s), ins = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 
        js.src = "http://domain.com/feeds/insert.js";
        ins.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ins);
        tryData(131, 'large');
        }(document, 'script'));
    </script>
    <!-- Widget End -->

</body>
</html>
```

here is the js file:

```
function data(){
    var u;
    u = document.URL;
    $.post("http://domain.com/data.php", { u: u} );
}

function tryData(id, size){
    document.getElementById('lsb').innerHTML = '<iframe src="http://domain.com/feeds/'+id+'/'+size+'/" id="frame"></iframe>';
    if(window.data){
        clearInterval(timer);
        data();
    }
}

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);   

timer = setInterval(tryData, 100);
```

Comment: You are calling it just like that, with hardcoded parameters?

Comment: what about using some kind of debugger ( each browser have one )

Comment: garbage in = garbage out. What parameters are being passed? Where do they come from?

Comment: Try debugging with Firebug and post more detailed examples regarding the HTML-page and JavaScript.

Comment: Sounds like a hoisting problem http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting

Comment: Yes I am calling it with hardcoded parameters. The debugger I have is the Javascript console on Chrome, showing no problems.

Comment: Can you post the code on fiddle.net? I posted your example there (http://jsfiddle.net/Pw2Nx/) and that seem to be working fine..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where are you passing the parameters?

Try this:

```
timer = setInterval(function(){
     tryData(131, 'large');
}, 100);
```

Comment: I tired this but it just seems to continually reload the page. I will play with it and see if I can get it to stick. Thanks

Comment: Just need to remove the "timer = setInterval(tryData, 100);" from my js file for this to work for me. Many thanks Alex.